# What does preceding a string literal with "r" mean?

Tags: python, string, syntax, literals, rawstring

I first saw it used in building regular expressions across multiple lines as a method argument to `re.compile()`, so I assumed that `r` stands for RegEx.

For example:

```
regex = re.compile(
    r'^[A-Z]'
    r'[A-Z0-9-]'
    r'[A-Z]$', re.IGNORECASE
)
```

So what does `r` mean in this case? Why do we need it?

Comment: Note that the splitting of strings over multiple lines within parentheses has nothing to do with the character prefix - this is just an example of Python's automatic string concatenation, and works with any prefix or none.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

The `r` means that the string is to be treated as a raw string, which means all escape codes will be ignored.

For an example:

`'\n'` will be treated as a newline character, while `r'\n'` will be treated as the characters `\` followed by `n`.

> When an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present,
>   a character following a backslash is
>   included in the string without change,
>   and all backslashes are left in the
>   string. For example, the string
>   literal `r"\n"` consists of two
>   characters: a backslash and a
>   lowercase `'n'`. String quotes can be
>   escaped with a backslash, but the
>   backslash remains in the string; for
>   example, `r"\""` is a valid string
>   literal consisting of two characters:
>   a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"`
>   is not a valid string literal (even a
>   raw string cannot end in an odd number
>   of backslashes). Specifically, a raw
>   string cannot end in a single
>   backslash (since the backslash would
>   escape the following quote character).
>   Note also that a single backslash
>   followed by a newline is interpreted
>   as those two characters as part of the
>   string, not as a line continuation.

Source: [Python string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: the backslash \`\\` cannot be the last charter or else an error `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` occurs.
For Python3 it is `print (r"Test\new")`

Comment: string interpolation using `.format()` still works on raw strings. [Formatting Examples](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 45):

It means that escapes won’t be translated. For example:

```
r'\n'
```

is a string with a backslash followed by the letter `n`. (Without the `r` it would be a newline.)

`b` does stand for byte-string and is used in Python 3, where strings are Unicode by default. In Python 2.x strings were byte-strings by default and you’d use `u` to indicate Unicode.

Comment: You forgot this: http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals