# How to delete () using re module in Python

Tags: python, regex, escaping, backreference

I am in trouble for processing XML text.
I want to delete () from my text as follows:

from `<b>(apa-bhari(n))</b>` to `<b>apa-bhari(n)</b>`

The following code was made

```
name= re.sub('<b>\((.+)\)</b>','<b>\1</b>',name)
```

But this can only returns

```
<b></b>
```

I do not understand escape sequences and backreference. Please tell me the solution.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Not everyone has english as his native tongue and is able to correctly and completely express what he wants to say (since english is a second language to me I've got a hard time as well quite often).

Comment: To me it sounded as if he doesn't (want to) understand the principle behind those things.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [raw strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/in-python-what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean), or escape the slashes:

```
name = re.sub(r'<b>\((.+)\)</b>', r'<b>\1</b>', name)
```

Comment: don't use a raw string for the first string, because `\\(` is not correct, `\(` is.

Comment: @boudou - Actually, You need to escape that backslash as well - the regex engine needs to see `\(`, so the string should be `'\\('`, or `r'\('` : http://ideone.com/X3tEN

Comment: Thank you! I did not know the use of raw string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape backslashes in Python strings if followed by a number; the following expressions are all true:

```
assert '\1' == '\x01'
assert len('\\1') == 2
assert '\)' == '\\)'
```

So, your code would be

```
name = re.sub('<b>\\((.+)\\)</b>','<b>\\1</b>',name)
```

Alternatively, use the regular expression string definition:

```
name = re.sub(r'<b>\((.+)\)</b>', r'<b>\1</b>',name)
```

Comment: No, he wants to escape parentheses, so `\(` is ok, not `\\(`.

Comment: @boudo `'\\('` is the same as `[(]`, i.e. match a parenthesis. `'\('` falls back to the default escaping. Your argument applies to regexp strings starting with `r'`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This can also return the results I want.

Comment: @boudou Yes, that's precisely what I tried to say by mentioning it falls back to default escaping rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
name= re.sub('<b>\((.+)\)</b>','<b>\\1</b>',name)
```

or if you do not want to have an illisible code with `\\` everywhere you are using backslashes, do not escape manually backslashes, but add an `r` before the string, ex: `r"myString\"` is the same as `"myString\\"`.