# as I hold the string of hexadecimal format without encoding the string?

Tags: python

The general problem is that I need the hexadecimal string stays in that format to assign it to a variable and not to save the coding?

no good:

```
>>> '\x61\x74'
'at'
>>> a = '\x61\x74'
>>> a
'at'
```

works well, but is not as:

```
>>> '\x61\x74'
'\x61\x74' ????????
>>> a = '\x61\x74'
>>> a
'\x61\x74' ????????
```

Comment: It's the same data. Why is that a problem? You are confusing Python's literal escape notation with the values they represent.

Comment: Maybe an explanation of Why would give us a clue to what your real problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *the same data*. Python lets you specify a literal string using different methods, one of which is to use escape codes to represent bytes.

As such, `'\x61'` *is the same character value* as `'a'`. Python just chooses to show printable ASCII characters as printable ASCII characters instead of the escape code, just because that makes working with bytestrings that much easier.

If you need the *literal* slash, `x` character and the two digit `6` and `1` characters (so a string of length 4), you need to double the slash or use raw strings.

To illustrate:

```
>>> '\x61' == 'a'  # two notations for the same value
True
>>> len('\x61')    # it's just 1 character
1
>>> '\\x61'        # escape the escape
'\\x61'
>>> r'\x61'        # or use a raw literal instead
'\\x61'
>>> len('\\x61')   # which produces 4 characters
4
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `r` prefix ([explained on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780104/882918))

```
a = r'\x61\x74'
b = '\x61\x74'
print (a) #prints  \x61\x74
print (b) # prints at
```

Comment: +1. You can also escape the backslashes… but using raw strings is easier, and more readable, so this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: You can also convert `a` to `b` using `a.decode('string-escape')` (if this is needed...).

Comment: @Bakuriu: No, `string-escape` would leave printable ASCII alone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, but this is not the case. If `a` is an "hex-only" string, as the OP wanted, then `a.decode('string-escape')` does convert it to `b`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: yes, `a` can decode to `b`, but `b` won't encode to `a`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I never mentioned converting `b` to `a`.