# What does the "r" in pythons re.compile(r' pattern flags') mean?

Tags: python, regex

I am reading through http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html. According to this  the "r" in pythons re.compile(**r**' pattern flags') refers the raw string notation :

> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with 'r'. So r"\n" is a two-character string
>   containing '\' and 'n', while "\n" is a one-character string
>   containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
>   code using this raw string notation.

Would it be fair to say then that:

re.compile(**r** pattern) means that "pattern" is a regex while, re.compile(pattern) means that "pattern" is an exact match?

Comment: `r` don't have any relationship with `regex`s. It just eases the pattern's string declaration.

Comment: Already great answers below, but just to clarify:  the answer is **no** to your last question which I'll paraphrase as *does `re.compile` without the `r` mean an exact match?*

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As `@PauloBu` stated, the `r` string prefix is not specifically related to regex's, but to strings generally in Python.

Normal strings use the backslash character as an escape character for special characters (like newlines):

```
>>> print('this is \n a test')
this is 
 a test
```

The `r` prefix tells the interpreter not to do this:

```
>>> print(r'this is \n a test')
this is \n a test
>>>
```

This is important in regular expressions, as you need the backslash to make it to the `re` module intact - in particular, `\b` matches empty string specifically at the start and end of a word. `re` expects the string `\b`, however normal string interpretation `'\b'` is converted to the ASCII backspace character, so you need to either explicitly escape the backslash (`'\\b'`), or tell python it is a raw string (`r'\b'`).

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\b', 'test') # the backslash gets consumed by the python string interpreter
[]
>>> re.findall('\\b', 'test') # backslash is explicitly escaped and is passed through to re module
['', '']
>>> re.findall(r'\b', 'test') # often this syntax is easier
['', '']
```

Comment: `\b` is backspace. `\a` is bell.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks, I always mix that up - I'll fix the post

Comment: I like the fact that you used an example to illustrate your point.

Comment: Thanks. Until now I thought normal strings and regular expressions were mutually exclusive, and thar r stands for regular expression, lol.

Answer (score 9):

**No, as the documentation pasted in explains the `r` prefix to a string indicates that the string is a [`raw string`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/in-python-what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean)**

Because of the collisions between Python escaping of characters and regex escaping, both of which use the back-slash `\` character, raw strings provide a way to indicate to python that you want an unescaped string.

Examine the following:

```
>>> "\n"
'\n'
>>> r"\n"
'\\n'
>>> print "\n"


>>> print r"\n"
\n
```

**Prefixing with an `r` merely indicates to the string that backslashes `\` should be treated literally and not as escape characters for python.**

This is helpful, when for example you are searching on a word boundry. The regex for this is `\b`, however to capture this in a Python string, I'd need to use `"\\b"` as the pattern. Instead, I can use the raw string: `r"\b"` to pattern match on.

This becomes especially handy when trying to find a literal backslash in regex. To match a backslash in regex I need to use the pattern `\\`, to escape this in python means I need to escape *each* slash and the pattern becomes `"\\\\"`, or the much simpler `r"\\"`.

As you can guess in longer and more complex regexes, the extra slashes can get confusing, so raw strings are generally considered the way to go.

Comment: Better answer since it actually explains *what* the r stands for ;)

Answer (score 2):

No. Not everything in regex syntax needs to be preceded by `\`, so `.`, `*`, `+`, etc still have special meaning in a pattern

The `r''` is often used as a convenience for regex that *do* need a lot of `\` as it prevents the clutter of doubling up the `\`