# python exact substring match

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of dishes and a sentence.

I want to check if a dish is present in the sentence. 
However, if I do a normal

```
if dish in sentence:
```

I will basically get a substring matching. My problem is that say I have a

```
dish='puri'
sentence='the mutton shikampuri was good'
```

the above code still matches puri with shikampuri which i don't want.

If I try tokenizing the sentence, I will not be able to match dishes like 
dish='puri bhaji'

Is there any way I can ignore the matches which don't begin with my dish string? Basically, I want to ignore patterns like 'shikampuri' when my dish is 'puri'.

Comment: word boundaries with re

Comment: Can your dish name be in the start of the sentence? if not, then I think that searching for " puri " solves your problem, with whitespace before and after your dish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need is `re.search` with `\b`.

```
import re
if re.search(r"\b"+dish+r"\b",sentence):
```

Comment: This was what I needed. Thanks :) 
On a side note, what does the 'r' in r"\b" represent?

Comment: @pd176: [What does the “r” in pythons re.compile(r' pattern flags') mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104476/what-does-the-r-in-pythons-re-compiler-pattern-flags-mean)

Answer (score 2):

You could write:

`if dish in sentence.split():`

This splits sentence by space into a list and looks for a dish in the list of words.

Comment: It's a nice, clean one-liner. I like it.

Comment: Yes. But this solution will not be able to find strings with spaces like e.g. dish='puri bhaji'. I missed that specification on answering. So the regex solution is the better choice here.