# Python: .str.replace(r'.*=','') not sure what it is being replaced with empty ""

Tags: python, string, replace, sklearn-pandas

I was studying Python and ran into the following statement for pandas:

```
humans['Education'] = (humans[
    'Years of post-secondary education (e.g. BA=4; Ph.D.=10)'] .str.replace(r'.*=','').astype(int))
```

I understand it creates additional column but not sure about `replace(r'.*=','')` function.

Comment: r'.*=' is a regular expression (RegEx), the . matches any character, while the star says match one or more of the preceding token (the dot). The final token = matches an '=' character. Anything matching this pattern will be replaced with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

This is a regular expression (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so the function replaces what matches the expression with nothing in you case (see the `''` given as second parameter).

To see what the regular expression is doing, you can use https://regex101.com/. In your case, it removes all text before the = sign (including the equal). Note that the `r` in front of the quoted string is explained here: [What does the "r" in pythons re.compile(r' pattern flags') mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104476/what-does-the-r-in-pythons-re-compiler-pattern-flags-mean/21104539)