# Python is not interpreting regex correctly

Tags: python, regex

I have this code:

```
import re

regex = re.compile("(.+?)\1+")
results = regex.findall("FFFFFFF")
print(results)
```

The expected result is:

```
['F']
```

According to [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/), the regex is doing what it is supposed to do (finding the shortest repeated substring). But when trying the regex in python [the result is `[]`](http://codepad.org/uMRpfbCa). Why is this?

Comment: Please post code here, not just as a codepad link.

Comment: It may be a codepad bug.

Comment: @Tuga: no, `\1` in a string is interpreted by Python as an escape before the regular expression engine can interpret it as an escape.

Comment: @MartijnPieters point taken!

Comment: Also see [The Backslash Plague](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) in the Python Regex Howto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use raw strings:

```
>>> re.findall("(.+?)\1+", "FFFFFFF")
[]
>>> re.findall(r"(.+?)\1+", "FFFFFFF")
['F']
>>>
```

Raw string literals, i.e. string literal prefixed with `'r'`, make the backslashes to be treated as literal.  Backslashes are otherwise treated as escape sequences.

Quoting from [`re` — Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> Regular expressions use the backslash character (`'\'`) to indicate
>   special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
>   invoking their special meaning. ...
>
> The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with `'r'`. So `r"\n"` is a two-character string
>   containing `'\'` and `'n'`, while `"\n"` is a one-character string
>   containing a newline. Usually patterns will be expressed in Python
>   code using this raw string notation.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
regex = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
```

Why didn't it work? You can understand by

```
print r"(.+?)\1+"
print "(.+?)\1+"
```

And see [What does preceding a string literal with "r" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/in-python-what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean)

Answer (score 3):

Use a raw string:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(.+?)\1+")
```

or escape the backslash:

```
regex = re.compile(r"(.+?)\\1+")
```