# How to encode and decode paths in python?

Tags: python, json, encoding, decoding

here is the problem, I want to dump and load windows paths in python under a unix system:

```
a = {"c":"a\b"}
b = json.dumps(a)
json.loads(b)
{u'c': u'a\x08'}
```

So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: `\b` is not `\\b` which is the real `\b`. Use `r"a\b"` instead. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/in-python-what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'\'` us being used for escaping `b` here. You can use `"a\\b"` or `r"a\b"` to avoid this problem.

```
a = {"c":"a\\b"} # or a = {"c":r"a\b"}
b = json.dumps(a)
print json.loads(b)['c']
```

**output**

```
a\b
```

Comment: Okay, but you use the print command to format it. What if I want to dump it to a file in the output format? Or hand it over to a function? Two things I need to do ... and thank you very much!

Comment: @Kai, you mean print `a` into a file. If you dump `a` as json, you can't avoid not printing `"a\\b"`. In other words if you print it in output format you can't reuse it as a json file.

Comment: I understand. So, if I load it from the file and hand it to functions, which of course need the "a\b" format, I just have to format it? Or should I format the dictionary after loading, before I use it?

Comment: Say `a = {"c":"a\\b"}`. Now you dump it to a file. It gets written as `"a\\b"` and read as `"a\\b"`. But, its actually `"a\b"`. So, after reading it, if you try to print `a["c"]` it would print `a\b`

Answer (score 0):

You failed to remember that the backslash character in a string literal can introduce an escpae sequence. "\b" represents the one-character string containing only a backspace.