# regex search&replace a variable string including a regex statement

Tags: python, regex

I want to use `re.sub` to replace a part of a string I know exactly what looks like. relevant part of code:

```
print "Regex statement: ", foundStatements[iterator]
print "string to replace with : \n", latexPreparedString
print "string to search&replace in: \n", fileAsString
processedString = re.sub(foundStatements[iterator], latexPreparedString, fileAsString)
print "processed string: \n", processedString
```

In my testing case, `foundStatements[iterator]` is `"%@import script_example.py ( *out =(.|\n)*?return out)"` But even though `processedString` contains `foundStatements[iterator]`, `processedString` looks exactly like `fileAsString`, so it hasn't accomplished the `re.sub` task. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Ok, it definitely has something to do with the string I'm searching to replace containing regex code. Is there a way to make it just interpret it `foundStatements[iterator]` as a raw string to search for? The only solution I can think of is to create a function that replaces any regex symbols in a string with \regexsymbol (e.g. * -> \*), but it'd make sense for there to be a way to solve this with inbuilt functions. It'd also be a bit overkill since I'd have to make sure it works with every single regex symbol, of which there are quite a few :/

**EDIT2**: Well, just changing it to `re.sub(re.escape(foundStatements[iterator]), latexPreparedString, fileAsString)` seems to work. except when the regex statement doesn't hit anything in the original file. To explain, `latexPreparedString` is generated by using the regex-part of the `foundStatements[iterator]`. While it's logical that it shouldn't be able to set `latexPreparedString` to anything when the regex statement doesn't hit anything, I set `latexPreparedString = "`" by default, so in that case it should `re.sub` replace it with a blank string if it doesn't hit anything. Here's how to code looks at the moment: [pastebin.com/wUedK3LN](http://pastebin.com/wUedK3LN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for replacing an exact match in a string, you should use `[string.replace()][1]`:

```
processedString = fileAsString(foundStatements[iterator], latexPreparedString)
```

However, this will still fail in your case, because `foundStatements[iterator]` has a newline character in it. To escape it, you need to use [the `r` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780104/1180926) when declaring `foundStatements[iterator]`.

If you still want to use `re.sub`, you have to both prefix the string with `r` and use `re.escape(foundStatements[iterator])` instead of `foundStatements[iterator]`. You can read more about `re.escape` [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape).

Comment: foundStatements is declared through a re.findall, so I'm not sure how to make that a raw string. I've subverted the problem by sidestepping it in my solution, but I'd still like an answer to how to do this. In my current solution I loop through all the hits twice - once to get all the information out of it, a second to replace it. Here's my code so far if that was hard to understand: [link](http://pastebin.com/Q10gqcXj). You can see it commented out where I was trying to insert the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: When strings are created from other functions (like `re.findall`), Any literals are already escaped; you only need 'r' when defining a string explicitly. You do still need to use `re.escape`, though