# Single letter before functions argument in Python

Tags: python

I am a python newbie and struggle to understand the usefulness of adding a single letter at the start of function's argument. Example is the following code:

```
reg_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]')
```

What is the role of `r` after `.compile(`?

If I run:

```
>>> reg_pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]')
>>> reg_pattern.findall('Thanks!')
```

I get:

```
['T', 'h', 'a', 'n', 'k', 's']
```

And if I run it without the `r`, I also get the same output. I also see other letter such as `u` in different functions.

Comment: re means regex and r' means raw data no escaping

Comment: this does not happen generally speaking. It is only for strings and does not have to be a function call. It simply tells Python to interpret the string as it is without paying attention to special characters such as `'\t'` for example. Try `print('\t')` and `print(r'\t')` to see the difference

Comment: `r` just tells python that the following characters are to be treated as raw characters. In python regex `\n` means new line character. `r` is used to avoid such confusions.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean)

Comment: Also see [string prefixes](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringprefix) in the documentation.

Comment: When you use regexes you usually prepend the strings with an `r` to avoid the [backslash plague](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague).