# How to read images with os.listdir(directory)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to read images by using `os.listdir(directory)` and Keras:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
from keras.preprocessing import image

img_path = 'D:\folder\train'

images = [(img, label) for (img, label) in zip(label_train.Image[:5], label_train.Id[:5])]

fig, m_axs = plt.subplots(1, len(images), figsize = (20, 10))
#show the images and label them
for ii, c_ax in enumerate(m_axs):
    c_ax.imshow(imread(os.path.join(img_path,images[ii][0])))
    c_ax.set_title(images[ii][1])
```

I received error on this line: `c_ax.imshow(imread(os.path.join(img_path,images[ii][0])))` error message `Invalid argument: 'D:\\folder\train\\00001.jpg`.

I'm using Python 3. How should I edit my code?

Comment: The `\t` in `'D:\folder\train'` will be interpreted as a `tab` character.  Try instead `img_path = r'D:\folder\train'`, the [`r` prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean) for the string treats the entire thing as a raw string, such that the `'\'` character will not be escaped.

Comment: Wonderful !! thank you!