# searching word following a giving pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I want get the word `'MASTER_INACTIVE'` in the string:

```
'p_esco_link->state = MASTER_INACTIVE; /*M-t10*/'
```

by searching reg-expression `'p_esco_link->state ='` to find the following word.

I have to replace date accessing to API functions. I try some reg-expression in python 3.6, but it does not work.

```py
pattern = '(?<=\bp_esco_link->state =\W)\w+'

if __name__ == "__main__":

    syslogger.info(sys.argv)

    if version_info.major != 3:

        raise Exception('Olny work on Python 3.x')

    with open(cFile, encoding='utf-8') as file_obj:
        lineNum = 0
        for line in file_obj:
            print(len(line))
            re_obj = re.compile(pattern)
            result = re.search(pattern, line)
            lineNum += 1
            #print(result)
            if result:
                print(str(lineNum) + ' ' +str(result.span()) + ' ' + result.group())
```

excepted Python re module can find the position of `'MASTER_INACTIVE'` and put it into `result.group()`.
error message is that Python re module find nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is working fine,

[image]

Just change the bellow line in your code,

```py
pattern = r'(?<=\bp_esco_link->state =\W)\w+'  # add r prefix
```

Check this sample work, I added `line` as your string.

```py
import re

pattern = r'(?<=\bp_esco_link->state =\W)\w+'
line = 'p_esco_link->state = MASTER_INACTIVE; /*M-t10*/'

re_obj = re.compile(pattern)
result = re.search(pattern, line)

print(result.span())  # (21, 36)
print(result.group())  # 'MASTER_INACTIVE'
```

Check below question to get more understand about `'r'` prefix,

- [Python regex - r prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241600/python-regex-r-prefix)
- [What exactly do “u” and “r” string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)
- [What does preceding a string literal with “r” mean? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean)

Comment: Your're welcome @PopeB.Lei and please make this answer as the accepted one. It will help for other developers to select the best answer surely.