# Why some characters of a string of words are missing and not?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-in-loop

In `email_two`, it contains a global string of some paragraphs which includes 'researchers' and 'herself'. I had to censor words of `email_two` from the `proprietary_terms` list (it subs into `term` in the function). However, when I used

```py
email_two_new = email_two.split()

for item in email_two_new:
    for i in range(len(term)):
      if item in term[i]:
```

it sliced off 'her' from 'researchers' and 'herself'. 'researchers' shouldn't be censored and 'herself' should be completely censored as it is on the list. I checked that 'researchers' is not in 'her' so it shouldn't be sliced off and `item` is printed as a whole string of each word instead of each character of a word, so I don't know what went wrong.

```py
proprietary_terms = ["she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"]
def censor_email_two(term):
  result = email_two
  email_two_new = email_two.split()

  for item in email_two_new:
    for i in range(len(term)):
      if item in term[i]:
        result = ''.join(result.split(term[i]))
      else:
        continue
  return result
```

Comment: What is the intended effect of calling `email_two.split()`. With no argument does it not simply make `email_two` an element in a list? Analogous to doing `[email_two]`?

Comment: You are probably better off looking for each term using a regex, with word boundaries. [Docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: @PyPingu I want to try to get rid of censoring 'researchers' since 'researchers' cannot be in 'her' and it is censored if I match `term[i]` with the whole string of `email_two`, aka to make the `if item in term[i]:` work.

Comment: @PyPingu but I cannot use regex with a variable like term? The term is supposed to change every time...

Comment: Can you post a short example of the `email_two` string?

Comment: Also you are returning `result` which will just be the unedited `email_two`

Comment: @PyPingu here's the paragraph before the problematic censoring:
```Not only that, but we have configured her personality matrix to allow for communication between the system and our team of researchers. That's how we know she considers herself to be a she! We asked!
```
That's how it prints.

Comment: @PyPingu I wanted the program to censor the term[i] for each loop, so `result` in the last term is supposed to return the edited email_two with all words censored from the list (`term`)?

Comment: Please post a __proper__ minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that this is best done using regex.

```
proprietary_terms = [
    "she", "personality matrix", "sense of self", 
    "self-preservation", "learning algorithm", "her", "herself"
]

def censor_email_two(email_string, terms, rep_str):
    subbed_str = email_string
    for t in terms: 
        pat = r'\b%s\b' % t 
        subbed_str = re.sub(pat, rep_str, subbed_str)
    #Run a split and join to remove double spaces created by the re.sub
    return ' '.join(subbed_str.split())

estr = "Not only that, but we have configured her personality matrix to allow for communication between the system and our team of researchers. That's how we know she considers herself to be a she! We asked!"

censor_email_two(estr, proprietary_terms, '')
```

Resulting string:

```
"Not only that, but we have configured to allow for communication between the system and our team of researchers. That's how we know considers to be a ! We asked!"
```

You can use the `rep_str` parameter to more easily see where there has been censoring:

```
censor_email_two(estr, proprietary_terms, "CENSORED")

"Not only that, but we have configured CENSORED CENSORED to allow for communication between the system and our team of researchers. That's how we know CENSORED considers CENSORED to be a CENSORED! We asked!"
```

**EDIT:** Added the `rep_str` feature

**EDIT 2:** Some further explanation on the regex.

So `r` indicates a [raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean).

Then `\b` is looking for a word boundary - from the docs:

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>   A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that
>   formally, \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W
>   character (or vice versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the
>   string. This means that r'\bfoo\b' matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)',
>   'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.

The `%s` is string formatting and is replaced by `t` which is each term in the loop. If you are using Python 3.6 or later this could be replaced by [combining `f` string notation with `r` raw string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#id43):
`fr'\b{t}\b'`.

I think technically you could use the `.format()` syntax too, but due to the raw string behaviour using the old `%` style is easier.

Comment: @PyPingy can you explain what `pat = r'\b%s\b' % t` means? I haven't learnt regex yet. Thanks btw.