# Can someone please explain to me what is happening in this line of code?

Tags: python-3.x

```
energy['Country'] = energy['Country'].str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")
```

I specifically do not understand what this part is doing -- `str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")`

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Context please. As there is no code of how `energy` was generated, there are a few options of what this piece of code could be doing.

Comment: Thank you for the info! Can you please explain to me what is happening at this part of the code `(r" \(.*\)","")`

Comment: In the future, you may want to refer to this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Will do - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `= energy['Country']` is getting the value from `energy` that corresponds to `'Country'`.

This piece could be separated as follow:

```
obj = energy['Country']
energy['Country'] = obj.str.replace(r" \(.*\)","")
```

Next, the attribute `str` is accessed from `obj`.
Again separating that out:

```
obj = energy['Country']
attr = obj.str
energy['Country'] = attr.replace(r" \(.*\)","")
```

And then the function `replace()` is called off of the value `str`.

**Note**, the value `str` here is not the same as the builtin class [str](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). Instead it is an attribute of the class that is returned from `energy['Country']`.

Comment: i guess the OP wanted to know  what `(r" \(.*\)","")`  exactly replaces in that string

Comment: It's a string literal. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780104