# How could I handle a file name as a variable in the with statement

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write data in a file. Here is how I proceed.

```
values = [45, 67, 39]
with open(os.path.join(path_class, r'first_file.csv'), 'a') as f: 
writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(values)
```

But I would like to have a variable at  first_file.csv position. 
My problem is here `with open(os.path.join(path_class, r'file_name.csv')`

So I would like to have something like:

```
list_of_file = ['first_file.csv', 'second_file.csv']
for i in range(0, len(list_of_file):
    with open(os.path.join(path_class, r+list_of_file[i]), 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(values)
```

How could I do that 
Thank you for taking your time to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
list_of_files = ['first_file.csv', 'second_file.csv']
for file in list_of_files:
    with open(os.path.join(path_class, file), 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need the `r` string flag here as the string represents csv file name only. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean) for use of the r string flag.

Hence this code should work:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_file)):
    with open(os.path.join(path_class, list_of_file[i]), 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(values)
```