# How to match strings and substrings from dictionary values

Tags: python

I have the following function to detect strings in my data, I joined both the key and values of the dictionary since I want to find both values. I added ^ and $ because I only want exact matches.

Function

```
import pandas as pd

def check_direction(df):
    # dict for all direction and their abbreviation
    direction = {
        '^Northwest$': '^NW$',
        '^Northeast$': '^NE$',
        '^Southeast$': '^SE$',
        '^Southwest$': '^SW$',
        '^North$': '^N$',
        '^East$': '^E$',
        "^South$": '^S$',
        "^West$": "^W$"}

    # combining all the dict pairs into one for str match
    all_direction = direction.keys() | direction.values()
    all_direction = '|'.join(all_direction)

    df = df.astype(str)
    df = pd.DataFrame(df.str.contains(all_direction, case = False))

    return df
```

I ran tests on the following series which worked as intended:

```
tmp = pd.Series(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday'])
check_direction(tmp)

0   False
1   False
2   False
3   False

tmp = pd.Series(['SOUTH', 'NORTHEAST', 'WEST'])
check_direction(tmp)

0   True
1   True
2   True
```

However I ran into problems here:

```
tmp = pd.Series(['32 Street NE', 'Ogden Road SE'])
check_direction(tmp)

0   False
1   False
```

Both returned as false when it should be True because of NE and SE, how can I modify my code to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what `^` and `$` mean.

- `^` matches the beginning of the whole string,
- `$` matches the end of the whole string.

For example, `'Ogden Road SE'` does not match the pattern `^SE$`, because the string does not begin with `SE`.

You probably meant to use *word boundaries* which are `\b`.

So you should change `^SE$` to `\bSE\b`, and so on.

You can make this less tedious and more readable by writing

```
direction = {
    'Northwest': 'NW',
    'Northeast': 'NE',
    'Southeast': 'SE',
    'Southwest': 'SW',
    'North': 'N',
    'East': 'E',
    'South': 'S',
    'West': 'W'}

all_direction = direction.keys() | direction.values()
all_direction = '|'.join(r'\b{}\b'.format(d) for d in all_direction)
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for clearing that up for me, last question for me is what does the r in ```r'\b{}\b'``` do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean