# Update cell in dataframe1 based on value from list in dataframe2

Tags: python

I have a dataframe1 with a column that has cell entries like so (each cell is a set of comma separated words) - `"are, boy, cat, dog, ear, far, gone"`.

Dataframe2 has a column with cell entries like so (each cell is a single letter or word) - `"are"` or `"boy"` or `"gone"`.

I want to add a column to dataframe1 that will have a boolean entry if a word in each cell in dataframe1 has the word in dataframe2. For example,

DF1 = (are, boy, cat, dog, ear, far, gone), (home, guy, tall, egg), (cat, done, roof, grass), etc.....

DF2 = (are), (boy), (gone), etc....

New column cell value in dataframe1 = (1), (0), (1), etc....

Comment: It would be better if in the future you gave a small and *complete* example (the third value in the new column values should be 0 according to the visible words), preferably with the python code to generate the sample inputs and expected result. This will help others understand what you want and make it easier to write up a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are your inputs,

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [
        'are, boy, cat, dog, ear, far, gone',
        'home, guy, tall, egg',
        'cat, done, roof, grass',
    ]}
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['are', 'boy', 'gone']})

print('%s\n%s' % (df1, df2))
#                                     A
# 0  are, boy, cat, dog, ear, far, gone
# 1                home, guy, tall, egg
# 2         cat, done, roof, grass, boy
#       A
# 0   are
# 1   boy
# 2  gone
```

We can use [`Series.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to convert the comma-separated strings to lists:

```py
df1['A'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*')
# 0    [are, boy, cat, dog, ear, far, gone]
# 1                  [home, guy, tall, egg]
# 2           [cat, done, roof, grass, boy]
# Name: A, dtype: object
```

The argument to split `r'\s*,\s*'` is a RegEx pattern matching commas and any whitespace between. [The `r` prefix means to treat the string literal as a *raw string*.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4780088/8944057)

Then we apply [`set.isdisjoint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.isdisjoint) to check which cells do *not* contain the values in `df2`:

```py
df1['A'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*').apply(set(df2['A']).isdisjoint)
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2     True
# Name: A, dtype: bool
```

And then finally negate this and assign to a new column `'B'`:

```
df1['B'] = ~df1['A'].str.split(r'\s*,\s*').apply(set(df2['A']).isdisjoint)
print(df1)
#                                     A      B
# 0  are, boy, cat, dog, ear, far, gone   True
# 1                home, guy, tall, egg  False
# 2              cat, done, roof, grass  False
```