# Web Scraping: Correct content is not being returned using BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I was trying to do scraping from AJIO website but it seems that the content which Python is fetching is not exactly same which I see while inspecting element of exact web page. It seems that some sort of java code is present on the page which creates HTML page in backend but when I try to fetch page content in Python, it shows me the java code instead of exact HTML page. Can any one suggest solution for this? Below is the code which I am using.

In the below code I am getting error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" after last line which is because the page is not correctly being fetched through "soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')". I can see "preview" class while inspecting the HTML page but when python fetch it, i cannot find "preview" class in it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://www.ajio.com/men-jeans/c/830216001?query=%3Arelevance&gridColumns=5"
page=requests.get(url)
ajio=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
print(ajio.prettify()) '''Problem

jeans_list = ajio.find('script',attrs={'class':'preview'})
for jeans in jeans_list:
    print(jeans_list.prettify())
```

Comment: Java*script* has nothing to do with Java, dont conflate them.   Anything can run on server to render html, but only javascript and wasm run in browser - flash and plugins like Java applets are and will remain dead.   It's certainly possible javascript is loading that content in subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks for your insights Daniel. So it means that javascript is loading the content on HTML page, that's why we cannot properly fetch content through python from this URL and cannot perform scraping.  Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want to parse this site you should get [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) object from [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) code. Than convert it to the Python dict and get Jeans data.

Your target looks like this

```
        <script>
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = {"wishlist":{}, 
    ....
          "apiStatusMessage":""}}};
        </script>
```

So, you can grab it with [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Pattern.search), parse it to dict and find the place, where your data is stored.

Here is an example how to find products' names and prices

```
import requests
import re
import json

url="https://www.ajio.com/men-jeans/c/830216001?query=%3Arelevance&gridColumns=5"
page=requests.get(url)

m = re.search(r' window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ({.+?}}});', page.text)

raw_json = m.group(1)
data_dict = json.loads(raw_json)


jeans_list = data_dict["grid"]["entities"].values()

for jeans in jeans_list:
    print(f"name: {jeans['name']}; price: {jeans['price']['value']}")
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing solution on this Eugenij. You are awesome.

I have a query, in the below line what is the significance of "r'" and "({.+?}}});"

m = re.search(r' window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ({.+?}}});', page.text)

Comment: @Salim Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted and upvote it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean) an explanation about `r'` strings.  This `({.+?}}});` is a part of regular expression that matches JSON. Here https://regex101.com/ you can try to play around regex and find out what does specific symbol means.