# Problem with Python code, executable_path

Tags: python

Is there an error in this line? The following words appear in red, executable_path, options, and when converting the code to an exe file, an error appeared in the same line

```
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\driver\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: File "wati.py", line 69, in connect_to_whatsapp
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Comment: what do you mean converting the code to an exe file? turns red where? Did you receive an error when you ran it?  if that error message you pasted as a comment was generated please put it in the actual question. and include more of the code to minimally expose the problem with needed information.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```py
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"D:\driver\chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
```

By adding the `"r"` character at the beginning of the string you make it a "raw string literal" the practical implication being that backslash characters `"\"` that would normally require escaping as `"\\"` can remain as `"\"` (single backslashes).

For more information, check out [What does preceding a string literal with "r" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780088/what-does-preceding-a-string-literal-with-r-mean)

Comment: Can you explain why this would fix the issue? If you did, it would make a fine answer.

Comment: Sure! by adding the "r" character at the begining of the path, it will change the path separator characters from "\" to "\\". I assume that is a blocker to run the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either escape backslashes (turn all single `\`into `\\`) or use normal slashes (`/`)

Comment: File "wati.py", line 69, in connect_to_whatsapp
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'executable_path'

Comment: Does your code work before compiling it to EXE? Please share the code on a fiddle